# Matplotlib: subplots function takes very long to execute

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following very minimal Python program has an execution time of ~112 seconds on my computer.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplots()
```

Calling the `subplots()` function is what causes this massive time delay.

I have *no* idea why this takes so long to execute, everything else works perfectly (including other functions in the `matplotlib` library). I should also add that this strange behavior suddenly started to occur, and I did not change anything in my Python installation, settings etc.

Is there anything I can do in order to fix this?

Comment: have you tried reinstalling matplotlib?

Comment: It works after reinstalling, thanks. :) But why did it not work before, I canged nothing in the installation/settings/...

Comment: not sure but i think as time passes and you use more storage, blocks in hard-drive gets filled and the sequence gets interrupted thus the system has to jump from blocks to blocks to get all the required code/library which increases time. That is why its very essential that we `defrag` our drives regularly so that everything falls in sequence. When you reinstalled matplotlib it created a new block and now again they are in sequence thus takes less time for the system to load it. I suggest you defrag your hard drive everynow and then. :)